# Docker for Mac: Host network and port publishing

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I am running Docker for Mac. When I run

```
docker run -d --rm --name nginx -p 80:80 nginx:1.10.3
```

I can access Nginx on port 80 on my Mac. When I run

```
docker run -d --rm --name nginx --network host -p 80:80 nginx:1.10.3
```

I can not.

Is it possible to use both "--network host" and publish a port so that it is reachable from my Mac?

Alternatively, can I access Nginx from my Mac via the IP of the HyperKit VM?

Answer (score 4):

**Without** the `--network` flag the container is added to the `bridge` network by default; which creates a network stack on the Docker *bridge* (usually the veth interface).

If you specify `--network host` the container gets added to the Docker *host* network stack. Note the container will share the networking namespace of the host, and thus all its security implications.

Which means you don't need to add -p 80:80, instead run...
`docker run -d --rm --name nginx --network host nginx:1.10.3`

and access the container on http://127.0.0.1

The following link will help answer the HyperKit question and the current limitations:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/

> **There is no docker0 bridge on macOS**
>
> Because of the way networking is implemented in Docker for Mac, you
>   cannot see a docker0 interface in macOS. This interface is actually
>   within HyperKit.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that with either of these approaches, there's simply NO WAY to make Mac docker containers accessible to other systems on the LAN?  That's a huge drawback to using the Mac.  I did see the above-mentioned "This interface is actually within HyperKit." but if the documentation author deemed that unworthy of a link, it suggests not to bother looking there just yet (indeed some searching came up with a lot of "not ready on OSX").

Comment: "Am I correct in saying that with either of these approaches, there's simply NO WAY to make Mac docker containers accessible to other systems on the LAN? That's a huge drawback to using the Mac." -- 

This is what I'm wondering/thinking too...